# MySQL check if two conditions return at least one result

Tags: mysql

**Problem:** I am trying to optimize the following into one query.

**Desired Result:** If both queries return at least 1 row, output True or 1. If only one query returns a result, output false or 0. Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT item_id
FROM  `category_item` 
WHERE  `category_id` =39610 AND `item_id` = 31

SELECT item_id 
FROM  `category_item` 
WHERE  `category_id` =37 AND `item_id` = 31
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `category_id`) 
FROM `category_item` 
WHERE `category_id` IN (39610,37) AND `item_id` = 31
```

you can add == 2 or > 1 for that matter

EDIT:
just to clarify:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT `category_id`) > 1) AS both_have
```

will result in return 1 or 0

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to check for rows is to use `exists` clause, and we can combine the two queries with `and` to make sure both queries return rows:

```
select 
    exists (SELECT item_id
        FROM  `category_item` 
        WHERE  `category_id` =39610 AND `item_id` = 31
    ) AND
    exists (SELECT item_id 
        FROM  `category_item` 
        WHERE  `category_id` =37 AND `item_id` = 31
    ) as `both_exist`;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlize.com/cx00raoMa7

Comment: Great answer! Hard to pick one! +1

Comment: This solution solved my particular problem , cannot say why first didn't